# How to render ejs file with external styles and fonts?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, path.js

I'm having trouble trying to write a pdf-generator node.js app. It renders an ejs template with data, and then sends the pdf file in base64 as a response. To convert html to pdf, using html-pdf-chrome and chromium. My problem is as follows:

After starting the app's server, I go to localhost:3000/path in my browser. While rendering it calls my function which is okay.  But on

```
ejs.renderFile('path/to/file.ejs',options, cb())
```

I get all content, but it is not loading styles and images.

I need something like

```
compileEjsFile->sendHtmlStringToConvert->saveFile->convertToBase64AndSend.
```

Is there any possibility to get full website (with rendered styles and images) from `ejs.renderFile()`? Is there any different way?

I know there is an option to pass the whole css after render, but unfortunately must add my own font and don't know how to do it properly.

In `file.ejs` the path to style is like this

```
<link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The app tree looks like this:

```
 - pdf (output pdf directory)
 - public
 - - stylesheets
 - - - style.css
 - views
 - - file.ejs
 - routes 
 - - documents.js (here is route that handles request)
 - tools
 - - generator.js (here im invoking `ejs.renderfile`)
```

Comment: You need to add `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` on your main file where your application starts. `path` is npm module to bind paths of directories.

Comment: Yes, i know that and i have this declaration, as i wrote, in browser page is rendered well, the problem occurs only when i call `ejs.renderFile()` to get rendered page. Is there any possibility to render a ejs file with absolute paths to images and styles?